# Mail laravel 5.5

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

i try to send email witl laravel 5.5 application with this config :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=malekbelouafi@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Always i get this error message:

```
 Swift_TransportException
    Process could not be started [The specified path was not found. ]
```

[image]
Any idea about ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to send mail via a simple `mail()` call? It looks like your overall  PHP mail config isn't set up properly.

Comment: Thank you for help, i try to send mail via simple mail,it doesn't work, i get this message: **Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp64\www\mail\index.php on line 2**

Comment: Yeah, nothing to do with Laravel then. Read the duplicates - it's a common problem.